# Cannot upload a file with chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test the file upload with Chai.

I've this **html**

```
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file/upload">
        <input id="file" type="file" name="filename">
        <input id ="submit"type="submit" value="upload">
      </form>
```

And this **API**

```
let fileStorage = require('../model/FileStorage');
let router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/upload', function(req, res){
let file = req.files.filename;
let filename = file.name;
file.mv('./upload/'+filename, function(err){
    if(err) {
        res.status(500).end("500: Internal server error");}
    else {//insert in db
        fileStorage.create({name: filename})
            .then(doc => res.send({message:"a "+doc}).status(200).end());
    }
});
```

When I send a file to upload through HTML, this code works.

the problem arises when I go to test, because the test case return state 500 and the test fails.

This is the **test case**

```
it('dovrebbe UPPARE il file', function(done){
chai.request(server)
    .post('/file/upload')
    .field('customKey', 'customValue')
    .attach('files', '/Users/francescovicidomini/git/ExampleNodeJS/server/upload/upload.txt', 'upload.txt')
    .end(function(err, res){
        res.should.have.status(200);
        done();
    });
```

Comment: You should print the `err` to see what happened